# AngularJS validation inside ng-repeat isn't firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

This is my first angular form.  The page has an ng-repeat that exposes a field to edit an existing value.  The value populates with no problem.  Each repeat has a separate form.  The error message isn't showing when the textbox is empty or if the pattern is wrong nor is the button disabling.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
<div id="ExistingTransactions" class="row">

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div id="items" class="row" ng-repeat="v in vc.transactions">

                        <div id="edittemplate" ng-show="editing">

                            <div ng-form="vc.myEditForm" ng-init="amountField = 'amount' + v.id; dateField = 'date' + v.id">

                                <div class="col-sm-1">

                                    <input
                                        id="btnUpdate"
                                        class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                                        ng-click="vc.update(v)" 
                                        ng-disabled="vc.myEditForm.amountField.$invalid || 
                                                     vc.myEditForm.dateField.$invalid"
                                        type="button"
                                        value="Update" />

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-2">

                                    <input 
                                        name="{{amountField}}"
                                        id="txtAmount" 
                                        class="form-control"
                                        ng-model="v.Amount"
                                        ng-pattern="vc.validate.currency"
                                        ng-required="true"
                                        type="text" />

                                    <div 
                                        ng-show="vc.myEditForm.amountField.$dirty && vc.myEditForm.amountField.$invalid" 
                                        class="text-danger" 
                                        role="alert">
                                        <div ng-show="vc.myEditForm.amountField.$error.required">An amount is required</div>
                                        <div ng-show="vc.myEditForm.amountField.$error.pattern">Please enter an amount in the correct format. IE: 12.56</div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: It may because vc.myEditForm is not unique for each ng-repeat. Maybe try something like `vc.myEditForms = []` in the JS and `ng-form="vc.myEditForm[$index]"` (and everywhere else) in the Markup.

Comment: Okay, just tried it.  That had no effect.

Comment: Okay, I think my instructions may have been wrong. `vc.myEditForms` should be initialised to any array of empty objects so that `vc.myEditForm[$index]` actually represents something. Maybe try that, otherwise create a Plunker, Fiddle, etc. and I'll help out.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the name of the amountField input to `{{amountField}}`, but trying to get the errors from an input named `amountField`. You'll need to set the name to just `amountField` or use the value of amountField to get the errors from the form object, ie `form[amountField]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Ben.  Unfortunately, that didn't have any effect.

However, I fixed it!  I moved the ng-form="vc.myEditForm" to a parent div above the ng-repeat.  Then I changed the

```
<div ng-show="vc.myEditForm.amountField.$dirty && vc.myEditForm.amountField.$invalid" class="text-danger" role="alert">
    <div ng-show="vc.myEditForm.amountField.$error.required">An amount is required</div>
    <div ng-show="vc.myEditForm.amountField.$error.pattern">Please enter an amount in the correct format. IE: 12.56</div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div ng-messages="vc.myEditForm[amountField].$error" class="text-danger" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">An amount is required</div>
    <div ng-message="pattern">Must be a valid dollar amount</div>
</div>
```

It now works as expected with validation of each row being independent of the others.  I don't understand why the ng-show approach didn't work inside the ng-repeat when it worked just fine for the input form.  Anyway, it's working.

Thanks for the help.